# why i use query of laravel is very slow

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

1.I use laravel version 5.6.
2.Database aurora MYSQL (AWS).

I query it's use approximately more than 1s for first query.
In category table had just 5 rows.

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [query] => select * from `admins`
>             [bindings] => Array
>                 (
>                 )
>
>             [time] => 1716.88
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [query] => select * from `category`
>             [bindings] => Array
>                 (
>                 )
>
>             [time] => 267.61
>         )
>
> )
> ```

First time use more than 1s always.

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [query] => select * from `category`
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                )

            [time] => 1379.56
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [query] => select * from `admins`
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                )

            [time] => 628.41
        )

)
```

use this

```
 $rows = Category::get(); 
 $rows1 = Admins::get();
 print_r(DB::getQueryLog());
```

How to fixing?
Thank you.

Comment: You may want to post your code as well to start. :)

Comment: If your DB is in the AWS cloud on a separate machine then you are likely experiencing network lag more than anything. You need to figure out how slow is the connection from your application to the database.

Comment: I already add the code.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I already test on nodejs also it's working fine. 300ms.